# Elementary proof that $\pi$ is irrational

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, irrational-numbers, pi

I'm trying to understand the first proof in [this](http://www.coolissues.com/mathematics/Pi/pi.htm) page. So we have

$$S=\frac{\pi }{4}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}=S_{n}+R_{n}$$

where $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}$ and $R_{n}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}$. Since the series is alternating we determine

$$0<\mid R_{n}\mid<\frac{1}{2n+1}$$.

Now we assume $S$ is rational. $S_{n}$ is clearly rational so $R_{n}=S-S_{n}$ must be a rational number. So far so good. But i didn't understand the next step. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: you didn't understand it because his argument means nothing

Comment: What do you mean? Is it wrong?

Comment: look at [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_PI_is_irrational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Laczkovich.27s_proof) for a (rational) proof

Comment: @esege I wouldn't say it's wrong: it completely meaningless.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong.  His claim is that $S$ is irrational because $S_n$ is rational (for each $n$) and $R_n$ tends to zero (as $n$ tends to infinity) but is never exactly zero.  In fact, this can be true when $S$ is rational as well; it doesn't tell you anything about $S$.  For instance, consider $1+(1/2)+(1/4)+(1/8)+\ldots = 2$.

Comment: Thank you @user1952009 . I'm sick of all the junk proofs on the internet.

Comment: @esege if you really want to learn math you should first study textbooks. Eventually you'll be able to tell which proofs are junk yourself.

Comment: You're so right @MattSamuel But when i study a textbook, eventually i get stuck at some part, to understand that part i have to look it up on internet, and a page, and another page. And i give up studying textbooks after wasting my time on junk proofs like this. So my problem is, i don't have a good study plan. Any advice?

Comment: Maybe ask a detailed question about it here.

Comment: The specific problem you're having with the textbook I mean.

Comment: everyone should have their share of enjoyment by reading some other articles from the same website http://www.coolissues.com/mathematics/sameauthor.htm I had met this site long ago and the arguments presented there are totally wrong. Perhaps it is written for cheap enterntainment / publicity and not knowledge.

Comment: Btw, an elementary proof of $\pi$ being irrational was given by Ivan Niven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The referenced article is
wrong, 
so wrong,
my god it's wrong.

It says
"For if the contrary is true, i.e. if  S is rational, then since Sn  is a rational fraction, the first of equations (2) says that a rational number S equals a rational number Sn plus, in view of equation (3), a non-vanishing fraction Rn, which is impossible."

This statement is absurd.
Here is an obvious counterexample:
$\frac12 = \frac13+\frac16$.

To explicate:
The rational number $\frac12$
 equals a rational number $\frac13$
 plus a non-vanishing fraction $\frac16$.

Poor guy.

Comment: I'm tempted to disagree with the first sentence and declare it [Not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong).

Comment: I thought of that too, but I feel that it has become a cliche.

Answer (score 3):

A proof that needs nothing else than elementary integral calculus was given by Niven here.

https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510788

Unlike the proof you post, you'll find this proof is correct. You can find a complete exposition of this proof in Ross's $\textit{Elementary Analysis}$ text.